# Change registry Value

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch file that makes multiple changes to component services. I am looking for the batch file to add Everyone, Authenticated Users, Administrators, and Anonymous Logon to the Com security tab of my computer.

I currently use a `.reg` file that would batch into the system but it does not take effect.

This seems to work on my Windows Server 2012 r2 test instance but not on a Windows 7 server.

For the Com security Access Permissions Edit Default permissions the registry value is saved into a `.reg` file called `COMSecurityEditDefault`:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\OLE]
"DefaultAccessPermission"=hex(3):01,00,04,80,98,00,00,00,A8,00,00,00,00,00,\
00,00,14,00,00,00,02,00,84,00,06,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,07,00,00,00,01,01,00,\
00,00,00,00,05,07,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,07,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,\
0B,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,07,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,\
00,14,00,07,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,0A,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,07,00,\
00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,12,00,00,00,00,00,18,00,07,00,00,00,01,02,00,\
00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,\
20,02,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00
```

I use a batch file:

```
chcp 1252>NUL
OleAutomationFeasibilityModel.exe /regserver
regedit.exe /s COMSecurityEditDefault
exit /b 0
```

Comment: Is the batch file being run as administrator?

Comment: Yes, it is being ran as Administrator.

Comment: The first line of you batch file seems to be useless. The second line should be `"C:\Full path to\OleAutomationFeasibilityModel.exe" /regserver` and third line `%SystemRoot%\System32\regedit.exe /s "C:\Full path to\COMSecurityEditDefault.reg"` to be independent on what is the current directory on execution of the batch file. If the files are in directory of the batch file, second line could be `"%~dp0OleAutomationFeasibilityModel.exe" /regserver` and third line `%SystemRoot%\System32\regedit.exe /s "%~dp0COMSecurityEditDefault.reg"`. `%~dp0` expands to path of batch file ending with ``\``.

Comment: And I hope this batch file is executed on Windows x64 in 64-bit and not in 32-bit environment as otherwise 32-bit `regedit.exe` is executed from `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` because of [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/file-system-redirector) resulting also in [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/shared-registry-keys) become active redirecting `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\OLE` to `SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\OLE`.

Comment: @moti this is some great information that i will take into consideration. I know that i will need to make a batch file for every operating systems 64 bit or 32 bit also. I have some other registry entries i need to find yet and need to make this one working first though. Again, thanks for all this information!